# How to get Datagridview from external class?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I need help with a DataGridView please.

I have a Form with a DataGridView and I have a Class, that creates and fills a DataGridView. But the data isn't shown in the Form. The DataGridView gets filled with DataSource.

Code of the Form:

```
Public Class Form1
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    Dim dgv As Class1 = New Class1

    DataGridView1 = dgv.Initialize()
End Sub
End Class
```

Code of the Class:

```
Public Class Class1
Private dgv As DataGridView

Public Sub New()
    dgv = New DataGridView
End Sub

Public Function Initialize() As DataGridView
    Dim ColumnName As String = "ABC"
    dgv.Columns.Add(ColumnName, "Text")
    dgv.Columns(ColumnName).DataPropertyName = ColumnName

    Dim sqlcmd As String = "select ABC from TABLE"
    'abstracted
    Dim TBL_Daten As DataTable = GetData(sqlcmd)

    dgv.DataSource = TBL_Daten

    Return dgv
End Function
End Class
```

In Debug I can see the DataGridView is filled.

Comment: Think about it. You have a `DataGridView` control that is displayed on the form because it has been added to the form's `Controls` collection. That same `DataGridView` is also assigned to the `DataGridView1` field. You are then creating another `DataGridView` and assigning it to that variable. Whgy should that magically display the other `DataGridView` in the form's `Controls` collection too?

Comment: Basically, that class is dodgy. It shouldn't know anything about any grid. It should simply return the `DataTable` that it created and populated. The form can then assign that `DataTable` to the `DataSource` property of the existing `DataGridView`. Anything to do with the controls on a form are the responsibility of that form.

Comment: "Whgy should that magically display the other DataGridView in the form's Controls collection too?"  
I thought, when I can work with the data with DataGridView1.DataSource, I could also work with the whole object.  
  
"It should simply return the DataTable."  
I would like to do the settings of the DataGridView in the class. If I later use the DataGridView in 10 Forms, I would have to do the settings in the 10 Forms.  
@jmcilhinney

Comment: Then you should be passing the `DataGridView` in from the form, not creating a new one.

Comment: I would prefer, if it would be a return value, but I changed it now to a Reference. I changed to     dgv.Initialize(DataGridView1) and     Public Sub Initialize(ByRef dgv As DataGridView). Thanks @jmcilhinney

Comment: There's no reason for that parameter to be declared `ByRef`.